# Razorpay Payment error : This payment has failed due to an issue with the merchant

Tags: razorpay

I have a test account with Razorpay and have been testing payments successfully.
Today I started getting this error.
I tried changing the test API Key and testing again and still the same issue.
The issue can be replicated with the following code in the repo.
https://github.com/cvsudheer108/CloudLabs/tree/main/RazorPayPaymentSample

In the sample, the Step2 is giving the error: This payment has failed due to an issue with the merchant.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: same error here, it was working a few weeks ago their github issue section has someone who posts a comment and closes the issue. Im kinda frustrated with them

Comment: Thanks for the update from your end,  Pemba Tamang! I just checked now and it is working now. I think it was a glitch from their end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no longer getting the issue now and the sample is working fine. I think it was a glitch from Razorpay end.